# Query performance of searching pattern

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, string-searching, query-performance

Posted the same question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941061/query-performance-of-searching-pattern), but did not get answer.

As per Andrey Nikolov comment, tried with [Trigram](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search), but the table name and column(more than 50 columns) are dynamic i mean will get from front end.

**Question**:

I have the following sample data for understanding the requirement.

Table:

```
create table ft_test
(
    col1 int identity(1,1),
    col2 varchar(max)
);

insert into ft_test values('John A Henry');
insert into ft_test values('Dsouza mak Dee');
insert into ft_test values('Smith Ashla Don');
```

**Creation of FULLTEXT INDEX**:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_test_Col1 ON ft_test(col1);

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ftcat
WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON ft_test  
(col2 LANGUAGE 1033)  
KEY INDEX UIX_test_Col1  
ON ftcat  
WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM
```

Notes:

> 1. Search for the given pattern in the given column of the table.
> 2. I have more than 200 millions of records in the table.
> 3. Created FULLTEXT index on required column.

Looking for best performing search query.

Givens:

> 1. Pattern: `oh`
> 2. Column to  Search: `col2`

Expected Output:

```
col1    col2
----------------------
1       John A Henry
```

Try:

1. Using FULLTEXT Index: `CONTAINS`

   ```
   SELECT col1, col2
   FROM ft_test1
   WHERE CONTAINS(col2, '"*oh*"')
   ```

No output.

2. Using FULLTEXT Index: `FREETEXT`

   ```
   SELECT col1, col2
   FROM ft_test1
   WHERE FREETEXT(col2, '"*oh*"')
   ```

No output.

3. Using Pattern Index: `PATINDEX`

   ```
   SELECT col1, col2
   FROM ft_test1
   WHERE PATINDEX('%oh%',col2)>0
   ```

Got an output.

Execution Plan: `Table Scan`

4. Using character expression: `CHARINDEX`

   ```
   SELECT col1, col2
   FROM ft_test1
   WHERE CHARINDEX('oh',col2)>0
   ```

Got an output.

Execution Plan: `Table Scan`

5. Using `LIKE`.

   ```
   SELECT col1, col2
   FROM ft_test1
   WHERE col2 LIKE '%oh%'
   ```

Got an output.

Execution Plan: `Table Scan`

Comment: @RandiVertongen, Looking for all matches.

Answer (score 2):

> ...tried with Trigram, but the table name and column(more than 50 columns) are dynamic...

There is no particular problem with using the trigram technique I wrote about in [Trigram Wildcard String Search in SQL Server](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search) with multiple columns, dynamic SQL, or 200 million records.

The comments on that article show people using the basic technique with multiple columns, much larger tables, and even with encryption. The modifications needed are normally quite straightforward, assuming the person making the changes understands the basic underlying implementation shown in my article.

Note though that *trigram* search requires at least a three-character substring to search for (as the name suggests). If you really need to perform two-character searches (as in the question example), more modifications would be needed, and you would need to carefully assess the costs and benefits with your data. Without further information, it would seem that a two-character match on hundreds of millions of rows would produce a great number of matches.

If n-gram search is not suitable for you, and you can tolerate some latency, an external solution like [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) might be worth looking into.

#### Example

The code below shows one way to extend the basic trigram search to work with three string columns in the same table. For brevity, it does not implement the trigger logic shown in my article to keep the trigrams synchronized with the underlying data. If this is required, the modifications needed follow much the same pattern.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Example 
(
    id integer IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    string1 varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    string2 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    string3 varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 
    CONSTRAINT [PK dbo.Example (id)]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id)
);
GO
-- 1 million rows
INSERT dbo.Example 
    WITH (TABLOCKX)
(
    string1,
    string2,
    string3
)
SELECT TOP (1 * 1000 * 1000)
    -- 10 characters numeric
    REPLACE(STR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1e10, 10), SPACE(1), '0'),
    -- 10 characters numeric plus 10 characters [0-9A-F]
    REPLACE(STR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1e10, 10), SPACE(1), '0') + RIGHT(NEWID(), 10),
    -- 30 characters [0-9A-F]
    RIGHT(NEWID(), 10) + RIGHT(NEWID(), 10) + RIGHT(NEWID(), 10)
FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS SV1
CROSS JOIN master.dbo.spt_values AS SV2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
GO
--- Generate trigrams from a string
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GenerateTrigrams
(
    @string varchar(255)
)
RETURNS table
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
    WITH
        N16 AS 
        (
            SELECT V.v 
            FROM 
            (
                VALUES 
                    (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
                    (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)
            ) AS V (v)),
        -- Numbers table (256)
        Nums AS 
        (
            SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.v)
            FROM N16 AS A 
            CROSS JOIN N16 AS B
        ),
        Trigrams AS
        (
            -- Every 3-character substring
            SELECT TOP (CASE WHEN LEN(@string) > 2 THEN LEN(@string) - 2 ELSE 0 END)
                trigram = SUBSTRING(@string, N.n, 3)
            FROM Nums AS N
            ORDER BY N.n
        )
    -- Remove duplicates and ensure all three characters are alphanumeric
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        T.trigram
    FROM Trigrams AS T
    WHERE
        -- Binary collation comparison so ranges work as expected
        T.trigram COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9a-z]%';
GO
-- Trigrams for Example table
CREATE TABLE dbo.Example_Trigrams
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    column_id integer NOT NULL,
    trigram char(3) NOT NULL
);
GO
-- Generate trigrams for string1
DECLARE @column_id integer = 
    COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Example', 'U'), N'string1', 'ColumnId');

INSERT dbo.Example_Trigrams
    WITH (TABLOCKX)
    (
        id,
        column_id,
        trigram
    )
SELECT
    E.id,
    @column_id,
    GT.trigram
FROM dbo.Example AS E
CROSS APPLY dbo.GenerateTrigrams(E.string1) AS GT;
GO
-- Generate trigrams for string2 
DECLARE @column_id integer = 
    COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Example', 'U'), N'string2', 'ColumnId');

INSERT dbo.Example_Trigrams
    WITH (TABLOCKX)
    (
        id,
        column_id,
        trigram
    )
SELECT
    E.id,
    @column_id,
    GT.trigram
FROM dbo.Example AS E
CROSS APPLY dbo.GenerateTrigrams(E.string2) AS GT;
GO
-- Generate trigrams for string3
DECLARE @column_id integer = 
    COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Example', 'U'), N'string3', 'ColumnId');

INSERT dbo.Example_Trigrams
    WITH (TABLOCKX)
    (
        id,
        column_id,
        trigram
    )
SELECT
    E.id,
    @column_id,
    GT.trigram
FROM dbo.Example AS E
CROSS APPLY dbo.GenerateTrigrams(E.string3) AS GT;
GO
-- Trigram search index
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
    [CUQ dbo.Example_Trigrams (column_id, trigram, id)]
ON dbo.Example_Trigrams (column_id, trigram, id)
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW);
GO
-- Selectivity of each trigram (performance optimization)
CREATE VIEW dbo.Example_TrigramCounts
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    ET.column_id,
    ET.trigram, 
    cnt = COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM dbo.Example_Trigrams AS ET
GROUP BY
    ET.column_id,
    ET.trigram;
GO
-- Materialize the view
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
    [CUQ dbo.Example_TrigramCounts (column_id, trigram)]
ON dbo.Example_TrigramCounts (column_id, trigram);
GO
-- Most selective trigrams for a search string
-- Always returns a row (NULLs if no trigrams found)
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Example_GetBestTrigrams
(
    @column_name sysname,
    @string varchar(255)
)
RETURNS table
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
    SELECT
        -- Pivot
        trigram1 = MAX(CASE WHEN BT.rn = 1 THEN BT.trigram END),
        trigram2 = MAX(CASE WHEN BT.rn = 2 THEN BT.trigram END),
        trigram3 = MAX(CASE WHEN BT.rn = 3 THEN BT.trigram END)
    FROM 
    (
        -- Generate trigrams for the search string
        -- and choose the most selective three
        SELECT TOP (3)
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY ETC.cnt ASC),
            GT.trigram
        FROM dbo.GenerateTrigrams(@string) AS GT
        JOIN dbo.Example_TrigramCounts AS ETC
            WITH (NOEXPAND)
            ON ETC.column_id = COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Example', 'U'), @column_name, 'ColumnId')
            AND ETC.trigram = GT.trigram
        ORDER BY
            ETC.cnt ASC
    ) AS BT;
GO
-- Returns Example ids matching all provided (non-null) trigrams
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Example_GetTrigramMatchIDs
(
    @column_name sysname,
    @Trigram1 char(3),
    @Trigram2 char(3),
    @Trigram3 char(3)
)
RETURNS @IDs table (id integer PRIMARY KEY)
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @column_id integer =
        COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Example', 'U'), @column_name, 'ColumnId');

    IF  @Trigram1 IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF @Trigram2 IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            IF @Trigram3 IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                -- 3 trigrams available
                INSERT @IDs (id)
                SELECT ET1.id
                FROM dbo.Example_Trigrams AS ET1 
                WHERE ET1.trigram = @Trigram1
                AND ET1.column_id = @column_id
                INTERSECT
                SELECT ET2.id
                FROM dbo.Example_Trigrams AS ET2
                WHERE ET2.trigram = @Trigram2
                AND ET2.column_id = @column_id
                INTERSECT
                SELECT ET3.id
                FROM dbo.Example_Trigrams AS ET3
                WHERE ET3.trigram = @Trigram3
                AND ET3.column_id = @column_id
                OPTION (MERGE JOIN);
            END;
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                -- 2 trigrams available
                INSERT @IDs (id)
                SELECT ET1.id
                FROM dbo.Example_Trigrams AS ET1 
                WHERE ET1.trigram = @Trigram1
                AND ET1.column_id = @column_id
                INTERSECT
                SELECT ET2.id
                FROM dbo.Example_Trigrams AS ET2
                WHERE ET2.trigram = @Trigram2
                AND ET2.column_id = @column_id
                OPTION (MERGE JOIN);
            END;
        END;
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- 1 trigram available
            INSERT @IDs (id)
            SELECT ET1.id
            FROM dbo.Example_Trigrams AS ET1 
            WHERE ET1.trigram = @Trigram1
            AND ET1.column_id = @column_id;
        END;
    END;
 
    RETURN;
END;
GO
-- Search implementation
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Example_TrigramSearch
(
    @column_name sysname,
    @search varchar(255)
)
RETURNS table
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
    SELECT
        Result.id,
        Result.string
    FROM dbo.Example_GetBestTrigrams(@column_name, @search) AS GBT
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        -- Trigram search
        SELECT
            E.id,
            string =
                CASE @column_name
                    WHEN 'string1' THEN E.string1
                    WHEN 'string2' THEN E.string2
                    WHEN 'string3' THEN E.string3
                    ELSE NULL
                END
        FROM dbo.Example_GetTrigramMatchIDs
            (@column_name, GBT.trigram1, GBT.trigram2, GBT.trigram3) AS MID
        JOIN dbo.Example AS E
            ON E.id = MID.id
        WHERE
            -- Residual exact match check
            CASE @column_name
                WHEN 'string1' THEN E.string1
                WHEN 'string2' THEN E.string2
                WHEN 'string3' THEN E.string3
                ELSE NULL
            END LIKE @search
            -- At least one trigram found 
            AND GBT.trigram1 IS NOT NULL
 
        UNION ALL
 
        -- Non-trigram search
        SELECT
            E.id,
            string = 
                CASE @column_name
                    WHEN 'string1' THEN E.string1
                    WHEN 'string2' THEN E.string2
                    WHEN 'string3' THEN E.string3
                    ELSE NULL
                END
        FROM dbo.Example AS E
        WHERE
            CASE @column_name
                WHEN 'string1' THEN E.string1
                WHEN 'string2' THEN E.string2
                WHEN 'string3' THEN E.string3
                ELSE NULL
            END LIKE @search
            -- No trigram found 
            AND GBT.trigram1 IS NULL
    ) AS Result;
```

That particular implementation choice allows trigram searches with the column name as a parameter:

```
SELECT
    ETS.id,
    ETS.string
FROM dbo.Example_TrigramSearch
(
    N'string1', 
    '%12345%'
) AS ETS;

SELECT
    ETS.id,
    ETS.string
FROM dbo.Example_TrigramSearch
(
    N'string2', 
    '%ABC12%'
) AS ETS;

SELECT
    ETS.id,
    ETS.string
FROM dbo.Example_TrigramSearch
(
    N'string3', 
    '%ABC45%'
) AS ETS;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should explain little  more about requirement than performance , one or two columns do not show seriousness of actual problem.

Anyway,`CONTAINS` and `FREETEXT` Query are not working because they do not search for letter between words or phrase.

They work for Words or phrase that begin with match letters,beside other conditions.[CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Also there is no point in using wildcard "*" before letters as it is not read as wildcard by CONTAINS and FREETEXT

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM ft_test1
WHERE FREETEXT(col2, '"jo*"')
```

So above query will return output because word start with `jo` is `John` .
Also notice '"jo*"' * is not use before,even if it use, it will ignore.

So clearly `CONTAINS`,`FREETEXT` are not your requirement.

Following link might help you,
[Partial word search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677204/using-sqlserver-contains-for-partial-words)